# Node.js container with docker-compose can't run

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I try to run a node.js container with docker.
Unfortunately, the container always stop and i can't get any log to understand why. When i restart the container, it instantly stops and i can't connect into it through the terminal.

About my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
    node:
        build: .
        container_name: node.cs
        restart: unless-stopped
        ports:
            - 3030:3000
        volumes:
            # app
            - ./app:/app
```

About my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10.9.0-alpine

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

# Set environment to "development" by default
ENV NODE_ENV development

# make port available outside of the image
EXPOSE 3000
```

As i suspect a permission conflict, here is my local working folder content:

```
drwxrwxr-x  2 myuser myuser 4096 août  30 00:07 app
-rwxr-xr-x  1 myuser myuser  791 août  30 06:41 docker-compose.yml
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser myuser  412 août  30 06:40 Dockerfile
-rw-rw-r--  1 myuser myuser   98 août  28 22:43 .dockerignore
```

Any help to understand what is wrong with my code is welcomed.
Thank you in advanced.
jB

Comment: Can you please add a bit more info? Your Dockerfile does not have a CMD, I assume you're trying to run an Express server or similar, but your container runs the default CMD of the node image `CMD [ "node" ]`. What are you launching exactly? I also do not see if you `npm install` it's not in the Dockerfile. Are `node_module` in your app directory? Did you try to use `docker-compose logs` to see the logs?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually i don't have any app ready with server.js ir package.json. I juste would like ti get the server to make some tests with the terminal. I will check the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:10.9.0-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g nodemon
# Set environment to "development" by default
ENV NODE_ENV=development

# Create app directory
# make port available outside of the image
CMD ["nodemon", "-L"]
EXPOSE 3000
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
   application:
   build: .
   container_name: whatever_name_you_choice
   restart: always
   ports:
   - "3000:3000"
   volumes:
   - .:/app
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It doesn't seem to work (nodemon doesn't solve anything) but i will investigate deeply.

Comment: Hello, with your files i get this error:
`ERROR: In file './docker-compose.yml', service 'volumes' must be a mapping not an array.`. After some change, the build seems to work but the container remains stopped. In docker-compose logs, i get:  `Attaching to my.container
node.cours | /bin/sh: [nodemon,: not found`. I hope it helps.

Comment: That only promblem of format when we copy paste. I test that file and that work normal... You may edited your yml format, I run this files to test them for you. The problem is i use single qoute instead dobble edit CMD like this `CMD ["nodemon", "-L"]`. My bad, I wrote that file and does't test them yet... Now it work..

Comment: I edited my file. You can copy them and try again... I so sorry

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

```bash
docker compose run server npm install jest
```

And it will work. Or else, your container node might a little bit old version, then just:

```bash
docker image pull node
```